# convert multidimensional php array to json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [110] => Array
        (
            [id] => 110
            [name] => example name 1
        )
    [220] => Array
        (
            [id] => 220
            [name] => example name 2
        )
)
```

When I json_encode it will become like this as a properties inside one object

```
{
   "110":{
      "id":110,
      "name":"example name 1"
   },
   "220":{
      "id":220,
      "name":"example name 2"
   }
}
```

I need it to become something like this:

```
[
   "110":{
      "id":110,
      "name":"example name 1"
   },
   "220":{
      "id":220,
      "name":"example name 2"
   }
]
```

As an array of objects so I can loop through the objects. Is this possible?

The purpose of this is to make it easier to loop through the json in another languages or frameworks.

Comment: This is because you have keys `110` and `220`, otherwise It would be two objects in an array.

Comment: You're trying to produce invalid JSON. Besides, you can easily iterate over what `json_encode` is producing here in any language.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON you can have lists or objects. Objects have keys, lists do not have keys. An associative array in PHP can only ever be an object in JSON.

The following is not valid list as it has keys:

```
[
   "110":{
      "id":110,
      "name":"example name 1"
   },
   "220":{
      "id":220,
      "name":"example name 2"
   }
]
```

The following is a valid list:

```
[
   {
      "id":110,
      "name":"example name 1"
   },
   {
      "id":220,
      "name":"example name 2"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (and thus JSON) arrays cannot have out-of-order array keys. It will always convert out-of-order PHP arrays to JSON objects to preserve the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that JavaScript stores json data in some magic way as well. But json is a Hash. Hash requires lots of space in memory and more than an array. Array stores all one after another in the memory and hash not. In order to access by index and by key you need to store another field or two json objects and synchronize between them. There is currently no design or programming pattern that do this for you. So after answering 2 times I edited and added another, proper answer :) If you want you can manually store an index which will point from your array to the object and turn it into json afterwards. `No magic scheme is here.`